# Adding image to quiz results javascript

Tags: javascript, image

I made a personality quiz and have everything working with an alert, but now I want the alert to tell me the specific result then for the page to go to maybe a pop up image or another page with an image reitering that results.

This is the quiz result part of the code.  Should I be adding in the images in the for loop section? or make another for loop?  I'm actually pretty new to JS and am not entirely sure what the next step is.

Should I be using  classes in any way shape or form? or is img.src the way to go?

```
var chosen = nations[0];

    for (i=1; i<nations.length; i++) {
        if (chosen.score <= nations[i].score) {
            chosen = nations[i];
        }
    }
    alert ("You belong to the nation of " + chosen.name + " !");
```

Comment: changing src is simple...start there

Comment: you want to use images in for loop.

Comment: I'm not sure what src you're referring to and step 1 for loop, got it, do you mean just making a new one after the for loop posted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are talking about a modal with different options based on a result. The above statement is definitely on track. Check out the JS Fiddle below that shows how you might implement some DOM manipulation based on a varied result.

[js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ssz90cqz/)

```
var win = 0,
    result = Math.random();

document.getElementById( "myBtn" ).addEventListener( "click", successImage );

if ( result < .33 ) {
    document.getElementById( "image1" ).style.display = "block";                
} else if ( result < .66 ) {
    document.getElementById( "image2" ).style.display = "block";        
} else {
    document.getElementById( "image3" ).style.display = "block";        
}

function successImage () { 
    win++;
    if ( win % 2 !== 0 ) {
        document.getElementById( "modal" ).style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById( "modal" ).style.display = "none";  
    }
}
```

Comment: Both of these comments definitely helped steer me!

Comment: Glad to help! As an aside once you get your feet wet with Vanilla JS DOM stuff, check out [jQuery](https://jquery.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You should create / change the image after the loop. It will be processed once the loop has completed. One way could be to place an image on the page, like maybe an ajax loading gif and obtain the images element and set the src to your new image when the loop is done such as

```
document.getElementById('imageId').src = 'myimage.jpg';
```

You could also create the image element on the fly like so

```
var image = document.createElement('img');
image.setAttribute('src','myimage.jpg');
document.body.appendChild(image);
```